# AspNet WebApi Polymorphic Parameter via Json $type convention not deserializing

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So here's the rub, I am actually doing this in Sitecore, but got so frustrated, I broke out a new boilerplate WebApi project, just to find my problem.

My assertion is that given the following request,

> /api/Simple/AspNetJsonDeserializing?instance={%20"$type":%20"SimpleWebApi.Controllers.ConcreteTestInstance,%20SimpleWebApi",%20"hostName":%20"google.com"%20}

I should get a non-null parameter value of `ConcreteTestInstance` for `ITestInstance` Instance in my `AspNetJsonDeserializing` Action Method.

However, Instead I am receiving the following exception:

> Cannot create an instance of an interface.

Instead, though if I use my `NewtonsoftJsonDeserializing` Action Method, and pass it a `jsonString` and explicitly deserialize it using the Newtonsoft `JsonConvert`, it will deserialize fine.

**What am I doing Wrong?**

Here's all the code

**The Json**

```
{  
    "$type": "SimpleWebApi.Controllers.ConcreteTestInstance, SimpleWebApi", 
    "hostName": "google.com"  
}
```

**Controller/Action**

```
[JsonInterfaceBindingAndNonDefaultConstructors]
public class SimpleController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult<string> NewtonsoftJsonDeserializing(string jsonString) // [FromUri] ITestInstance instance) //   
    {

        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettingForTypeHandling = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor };
        ITestInstance instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ITestInstance>(jsonString, jsonSerializerSettingForTypeHandling);
        return Json("OK");
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult<string> AspNetJsonDeserializing([FromUri] ITestInstance instance)
    {
        return Json($"Uri:{((ConcreteTestInstance)instance)._instanceUri}");
    }
}
```

**Attribute for modifying SerializerSettings**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class JsonInterfaceBindingAndNonDefaultConstructors : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        IEnumerable<JsonMediaTypeFormatter> jsonFormatters = controllerSettings.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>();
        foreach (var jsonFormatter in jsonFormatters)
        {
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();  //new JsonContractResolver(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() {});
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ITestInstance
{
}
```

**Concrete Subclass**

```
public class ConcreteTestInstance : ITestInstance
{
    private const string SCHEME = "http://";
    private const int PORT = 80;
    private const string API_PATH = "/";
    private const string QUERYSTRING = "";


    public readonly Uri _instanceUri;

    public ConcreteTestInstance(string hostName)
    {
        _instanceUri = new UriBuilder(SCHEME, hostName, PORT, API_PATH, QUERYSTRING).Uri;
    }
}
```

**Exception: Cannot create an instance of an interface.**

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Cannot create an instance of an interface.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.MissingMethodException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.CreateModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.EnsureModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContextExtensions.Bind(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable`1 binders) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.CompositeModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update.

I have changed a few things, which have provided some new results.

First I have switched the `AspNetJsonDeserializing` attribute to `HttpPost`.

I have also switched the `AspNetJsonDeserializing` parameter `ITestInstance instance` attribute to `[FromBody]`

Obviously now, this if forcing me to call it via PostMan.

All of this has now removed the exception, but the instance is null. No breakpoints are hit on the ConcreteTestInstance constructors (I added another zero-parameter constructor to validate it both ways).

Here are the changes all together.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult<string> AspNetJsonDeserializing([FromBody] ITestInstance instance)
{
    ConcreteTestInstance myConcreteTestInstance = ((ConcreteTestInstance) instance);
    return Json($"Uri:{myConcreteTestInstance._instanceUri}");
}
```

**So short story, I am still on the hunt, for why  `instance` is null**

Answer (score 0):

Another update.

I have got the code working now with a HttpPost. The problem was the json formatting :FACEPALM:

In PostMan I was using the format

```
{instance: {  
    "$type": "SimpleWebApi.Controllers.ConcreteTestInstance, SimpleWebApi", 
    "hostName": "google.com"  
}}
```

When I removed the instance variable, it corrected the issue.

Also, I tested, and the `[FromBody]` attribute on the ITestInstance parameter, was irrelevant.

**So the issue still remains as to how do I enable this functionality as an HttpGet**.

At the moment, when I switch the attribute from HttpPost to HttpGet, I start recieving the exceptions mentioned in the first post.